# Core data number of attributes in Entity

Tags: xcode, core-data

I am new to core data I would appreciate some assistance in the code below that I need to display the number of attributes in an entity;

```
    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    //NSUInteger attributeCount = [[[object entity] attributesByName] count];
    float valueSF = 0;
    for (NSManagedObject *object in [sectionInfo objects]) {
        NSUInteger attributeCount = [[[object entity] attributesByName] count];
        valueSF += [[object valueForKey:@"value"] floatValue];
        valueSF = valueSF / attributeCount;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[Average = %.03f] [Cases = %i]", valueSF, [[sectionInfo objects] count]];

}
```

Comment: Do you really want the number of attributes? For the average value in the section you would have to divide by the number of objects in the section, i.e. divide by `[[sectionInfo objects] count]`.

Comment: Thanks Martin, this helped in displaying the number of objects but the average of the values in the fields is not displaying correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core Data provides good introspection. Assuming you mean the number of attributes actually declared for the entity in the data model, you'd want:

```
NSUInteger attributeCount = [[[object entity] attributesByName] count];
```

If you want to include the number of relationships, replace `attributesByName` with `propertiesByName`.

Comment: Thanks Tom I edited the code as suggested but the valueSF is still being calculated as the total rather than average

Comment: You probably don't want to divide by `attribuetCount` until after you've finished adding up all of the `value`s. Dividing at each pass through the loop doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Solved by adding int attributeCount;
    attributeCount = [[sectionInfo objects] count];
and dividing outside the loop.

Comment: Good to hear, but you should use `NSUInteger` to match the return type of `count`.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy now. Number of Attributes for the Particular entity capture by below function:

```
NSInteger count=[managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```